# Calling a method in main doesn't call because a JFrame keeps it from running

Tags: java, swing

I have made a small platformer game, but I can't get any game logic to execute.  I have figured out that this is caused because for some reason, the game gets caught on `createFrame()`.

How can I get `customUpdate()` to run when the code gets caught on `createFrame()`?  I have tried calling the code inside of `createFrame()`, but that creates infinite `JFrame` windows.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Main extends JPanel {
    private boolean running = true;
    private Player player = new Player(50,50,25,50,100, 100);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main main = new Main();


        main.createFrame();
        while (main.running) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000 / 60);
                main.customUpdate();
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private void createFrame() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Matt's game");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(800,500);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.add(this);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void customUpdate() {

        this.revalidate();
        player.changePlayerX(1);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillRect(player.getPlayerX(), player.getPlayerY(), player.getPlayerWidth(), player.getPlayerHeight());
    }
}
```

Comment: use a new Thread for the UI.  `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      // Here, we can safely update the GUI
      // because we'll be called from the
      // event dispatch thread
      
    }
  });`

Comment: Do I call SwingUtilities inside of customUpdate()?  It doesn't work on outside of a method, and it looks like I should be calling it there looking at some examples on google.

Comment: 1) `Thread.sleep(1000 / 60);` change that to a Swing based `Timer`. 2) Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread).  The GUI will 'freeze' when that happens.  See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for details and the fix. 3) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: 4) *"Calling a method in main doesn't call .."* BTW - most of the stuff in the main method should be moved into a constructor for the (poorly named) `Main` class. As to a better name, something more descriptive, like `PlayerAnimationComponent`would be easier for the reader (whether that's us, now or you in 6 months when you revisit this code).

Comment: @AndrewThompson Your comment fixed my issue.  You should post that as an answer so I can accept it.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: I cannot add an answer when a question has been closed, but that's not important now you have *the solution*. Glad you figured it out. :)

Answer (score 0):

While I agree with comments, here is an example (without thread) and basically "repainting" based on some events...

Since your `Player` class was not available, I tried with "boolean" that changes the color of player. :) And it changes player based on mouse event. You can update based on your event.. Also I need to call repaint..

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

public class Main extends JPanel {

    private boolean running = true;
    //private Player player = new Player(50, 50, 25, 50, 100, 100);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main main = new Main();

        main.createFrame();
        main.addMouseListener( new MouseAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent ex)
            {
                main.customUpdate();
            }

});
       // main.customUpdate();
       /* while (main.running) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000 / 60);
                main.customUpdate();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }*/
    }

    private void createFrame() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Matt's game");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(800, 500);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.add(this);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void customUpdate() {

        this.revalidate();
        this.repaint();
        //player.changePlayerX(1);
        System.out.println("Player changed...");
    }
    boolean isRed=false;
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
                System.out.println("red..."+isRed);
        if(isRed)
        {
         g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        }
        else
        {
            g.setColor(Color.red);
        }

        isRed=!isRed;
        g.fillRect(10, 10, 100, 100);
        //g.fillRect(player.getPlayerX(), player.getPlayerY(), player.getPlayerWidth(), player.getPlayerHeight());
    }
}
```

Comment: So this would call when a Mouse is clicked, right?  Is there a way to get it to call every 1/60th of a second?

Comment: Yes why not. Start a timer, and then update it.. or like you were doing... Run in loop but in a separate thread...